# Automatically run macro if the user inserted a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my macro to run automatically if it detects that the user inserted a new worksheet into the workbook (existing & new).

```
 Sub macro_run()

    Dim Newws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sample1 As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sample1 = .Sheets("Template")

        For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
            If Newws = sample1 Then
                Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Opennew"
            End If
        Next wb
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The [`Workbook.NewSheet` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-newsheet-event-excel) occurs when a new sheet is added in `ThisWorkbook` - but it sounds like you want to detect worksheet insertion in any open workbook?

Comment: yes, is there any ways i can do that?

Comment: you can probably do that using Application-level events  - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn254092.aspx and http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx  EDIT - if you don't need to detect "new workbook" events then you can just use a collection of "with events" workbook references

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah, the [Application.WorkbookNewSheet Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-workbooknewsheet-event-excel)

Comment: but is it possible for it to run automatically without i manually run it whenever i start a new workbook?

Comment: Yes - for more detail on Events, read http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to handle `WorkbookNewSheet` at `Application` level.

---

```
'-- Create a new Class.
'-- Name it clsGlobalHandler.
'-- Following Code goes in that class

'/ Create a variable to hold Application Object
Public WithEvents xlApp As Application

'/ Handle NewSheet event. Invoked whenever a new sheet is added
Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookNewSheet(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Sh As Object)
    MsgBox Sh.Name
End Sub
```

---

```
'-- Create a new module
'-- Following code goes there

Option Explicit

'/ A new instance  for the Class that we created.
Dim oGh As New clsGlobalHandler

'/ To start tracking sheet additions call this method first. Most likely in WorkBook_Open
'/ Once called any new sheet across the app insatnce will be intercepted.
Sub SetGlobalHandler()
    Set oGh.xlApp = Application
End Sub

'/ Call this to remove the global handler.
Sub ResetGlobalHandler()
    Set oGh.xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, there is a compile error; user define type not defined for Dim oGh As New clsGlobalHandler

Comment: read the code comments. don't copy paste blindly. you need to create a class with the name of clsGlobalHandler .